# What's the least intrusive method for creating a backup of a couchdb database?

Tags: couchdb

We're looking to create regular backups of a couchdb database, to ship offsite. What's the least intrusive way to obtain these - ideally without interrupting or significantly slowing down performance on the existing database server?

Comment: Serverfault would be a much better place for this, or perhaps SO

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Luckily couchdb is append only, so just copy the file and you'll have a non-corrupt backup.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to take a more programmatic approach just use the _all_docs URI, from [wiki.apache.org](http://wiki.apache.org/couchdb/HTTP_Document_API#all_docs)

```
GET somedatabase/_all_docs HTTP/1.0
```

The response will get you a list of all the documents in the database.

Using replication to backup the database is another [possibility](http://wiki.apache.org/couchdb/Frequently_asked_questions?action=show&redirect=FrequentlyAskedQuestions#how_replication).

Just post the source/target database names to the _replicate URI.